# Running a javascript function that is in an external .js file from within the script? (attached by src=) Using PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I'm using PHP code to generate the  tag in the  tags of my webpage.

I'm using PHP so that if a particular GET variable has been set (in this case, 'savedsearch') it runs a functions from the external javascript file I'm attaching to the web page.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php
//check if a saved search has been used
if (isset($_GET["savedsearch"])) {
    $savedsearch=$_GET["savedsearch"];
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='search.js'>
    window.onload=sendsearch($savedsearch);
    </script>";
}
else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='search.js'></script>";
}
?>
```

This isn't working (doesn't run the function if the savedsearch is set)... is running a functions like this possible?

Is there any other way I can do this without having any javascript or PHP in the body of my page?

Help appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Protip: drop out of PHP mode to echo HTML snippets: `if ($condition) { ?><script>console.log("hello, world")</script><?php }`

Comment: @WaleedKhan Didn't realise that was possible, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a script tag with a src attribute the code inside that tag is not executed, you'll have to add another tag to execute the code, a script tag can't be used to fetch a script and to run inline scripts.

You also are assigning the result of `sendsearch()` to `window.load` which is not a function. The only reason it's kind of working is because you don't really need to wait for onload event in your case? It's being called as the script is parsed, not after the window.onload event.

Also, be sure to call `json_encode` on the `$savedsearch`, that will prevent XSS and string escaping problems  (while also adding the quotes around your string).

```
<?php
//check if a saved search has been used
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='search.js'></script>";
if (isset($_GET["savedsearch"])) {
    $savedsearch=json_encode($_GET["savedsearch"]);
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
       // If you don't need to wait for the onload event
       sendsearch($savedsearch);
       // If you do need to wait for the onload event
       window.onload = function(){
         sendsearch($savedsearch);
       };
    </script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: It's the root of the problem, but you should update the answer to explain that the OP probably wants to run `window.onload=function(){sendsearch("$savedsearch")}`, that is, onload should be a function and the parameter to sendsearch should probably be wrapped with quotes. Also note that if the string has a quote in it, it won't work, the best way is to use json_encode($savedsearch). Lastly, you shouldn't use an unsanitized value from the query string in your JS, since that means anyone could run javascript on the page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: @JuanMendes Yes after implementing the quote marks it works fine (even without nesting it in another function) as the function runs an ajax request.. the query did have quotes in it but I've worked around it with some str_replace functions... messy it's only a personal project and short on time.. so thanks for the tips, ill be sure to use in future!

Musa, thanks a bunch, works perfect

Comment: @user1952067 That means that your AJAX request is being sent before the `window.onload` event, it's being sent when you assign the result of your function to `window.onload`. If that behavior is fine, you don't need `window.onload=sendsearch(...)`, just run the function directly. Also, don't use `str_replace`, I'm sure you didn't handle all possible characters that may need to be escaped. If I offered you a foolproof way `json_encode`, why would you hack it up? `json_encode` will also protect you from XSS.

Comment: @JuanMendes no problem except `$savedsearch` was already encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try:

```
<?php
//check if a saved search has been used
if (isset($_GET["savedsearch"])) {
    $savedsearch=$_GET["savedsearch"];
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='search.js'></script>
          <script>
            window.onload=sendsearch($savedsearch);
          </script>
         ";
}
else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='search.js'></script>";
}
?>
```

Having src and content both in the script tag at once is unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the content/src problems outlined in the others' answers, but unless your `sendsearch` function *returns a function* this won't work. You'll need to have the following instead:

```
window.onload=function(){sendsearch($savedsearch)};
```

This provides a function which can be run when the `onload` event is called.

This might need to be used in conjunction with pulling the javascript into a different tag, as per the other answers - I'm not familiar with how that might work.